# Is it correct for stored procedure to return dynamic number of columns?

Tags: stored-procedures

Is it good practice for a stored procedure to return dynamic number of columns?

For example, based on the input value the stored procedure decides what output columns to add or remove.

Answer (score 0):

It's fine as long as the consuming application(s) can handle it.

Comment: But since not all consuming application like hibernate in java can handle it, should it not be a bad practice?

Comment: Well, only if you're writing a stored procedure that might be consumed by hibernate or some other application that can't handle it.   Usually when you write a stored procedure, you know what application will be consuming it, so you can write in an optimal way for that application.